# Как отправлять фотографии в канал, если мне известна лишь ссылка и сохранять фотографию локально не требуется

Tags: java, telegrambots

В интернете я нахожу способы отправки фотографий, когда у меня данная фотография есть на сервере/компьютере, но как мне отправлять фотографию, на которую у меня есть ссылка (=URL)?

Answer (score 0):

Для такого случая достаточно использовать стандартный набор в Java.

Как вариант, попробуйте следующий способ:

```
SendPhoto message = new SendPhoto();
message.setPhoto("photo", new URL("https://www.example.com/photo.jpg").openStream());
message.setCaption("Caption text here");
message.setChatId(post.getChatId());
try {
  new BotName().execute(message);
} catch (TelegramApiException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```